# What is the meaning of "... is [noun] is [same noun]" in repetition?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

A while back, Lin-Manuel Miranda wrote in his poem about the Pulse shooting:

> "Love is love is love is love is love is love is love is love..."

Initially, I thought that the lack of grammar was just the flexibility of poetic form, but recently Joe Biden tweeted something of a similar structure:

> "Enough is enough is enough."

Is there any guideline to using this type of structure? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in Joe Biden's case, he is using the repetition of the word 'enough' purely as emphasis, as in "This is really, truly enough."

For the poem, whilst I lack the context as I haven't read any of Lin-Manuel Miranda's works, I believe that would again be emphasising that all forms of love are the same; 'this type of love is that type of love, and all types of love are love.'

Comment: You may never have read any of Miranda's works, but chances are you've heard it: he's the author, lyricist, composer and original star of *Hamilton*.